# Async for-loop not advancing past first iteration in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I have an array of video info from a YouTube playlist. I'm trying to retrieve the audio of each video using npm module [youtube-mp3-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-mp3-downloader).

I'm want to iterate over the array asynchronously, in sequence.

The array I'm iterating has a bunch of objects like the following one:

```
{
    snippet: {
      title: 'Video Title'
    },
    contentDetails: {
      videoId: 'video-Id'
    }
}
```

I'm running the following loop and it successfully runs the 1st iteration (downloads the audio file and resolves the promise). Then it enters the 2nd iteration, it does `console.log("started iteration " + i)` but stops right there, before entering `await getFromYT()`

```
async function getAudio(list) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        console.log("started iteration " + i)
        await getFromYT(list[i]).then(message =>
            console.log(message + " " + i)
        ).catch(error =>
            console.log(error)
        )
    }
}
```

here is what I get in the console:

```
started iteration 0
Finished 0
started iteration 1
```

And here is the function that is being `await`ed:

```
function getFromYT(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        YD.download(item.contentDetails.videoId, item.snippet.title + '.mp3');
        YD.on("error", function (error) {
            reject(error);
        });
        YD.on("finished", function (err, data) {
            resolve("Finished");
        });
    })
}
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and haven't gotten anywhere.

Ideally I would like to know what's wrong with the code that I have. Why doesn't it continue the loop?

However, if you can suggest a straight forward way to achieve what I'm trying to do that would be helpful too.

Comment: What is `YD`? Multiple `getFromYT` calls seem to install `error` and `finished` error handlers on the same object and call its `.download()` method multiple times, which probably is the reason for the second call not getting finished.

Comment: @Bergi `YD` is the module youtube-mp3-downloader. The point of the async/await in this code is that the each additional call to `getFromYT` only starts after the previous one has finished. So it's not being called multiple times (at least not while it's in operation). Additionally there doesn't appear to be any errors.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you will need to instantiate a `new YoutubeMp3Downloader(…)` for each video download - put it inside the `new Promise` executor in `getFromYT`.

Comment: Ok, after taking a look at [the code](https://github.com/ytb2mp3/youtube-mp3-downloader/blob/master/lib/YoutubeMp3Downloader.js): no, a separate instance shouldn't be necessary. However, the library you're using has its own queue management built-in, it expects you to call `download` with all items of your list at once, it will then use the `queueParallelism`, not a strictly serial approach like your await-loop. For your use case, I would recommend to not use the queued `download` method but to promisify the `performDownload` method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing async/await style and promises. the function which loops through should look like this

```
async function getAudio(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    try {
      console.log("started iteration " + i)
      const message = await getFromYT(list[i]);
      console.log(message + " " + i);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

if the operations can be done in parallel, consider using `Promise.all` with `.map`

Comment: This doesn't solve or attempt to explain why the iteration fails to advance. The choice of syntax is unrelated. Your code is functionally equivalent to that in the question, regardless of style.

Comment: @Ashish Modi thank you for pointing out the mixing of async/await and promises styles. That is helpful to know. However, as Patrick Roberts pointed out, functionally the're the same and after updating my code with the code you provided the results were identical to the prior results.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd do the same using a combination of async/await and Promise.

```
const getFromYT = (item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    YD.download(item.contentDetails.videoId, item.snippet.title + '.mp3');
    YD.on("error", (error) => {
        reject(new Error(error));
    });
    YD.on("finished", (err, data) => {
        resolve({ id: item.id, data});
    });
});

const getAudio = async (list) => {
    const promises = list.map((listItem) => {
        return getFromYT(listItem)
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
    let data = null;
    try {
        data = await Promise.all(promises);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return data;
};
```

So, what I've done here is simply instantiated all the promises together in a loop using the `map` function.

Then, I execute all the promises parallely using `Promise.all` and `await` for all the promises to resolve parallely.

I ensure that the promise chain in `getAudio` doesn't break by catching rejections at the individual `getFromYT` promises itself.

You can get the data and the corresponding item without any mismatch as follows :-

```
const allData = await getAudio(list);

allData.forEach((datum) => {
    const { id, data } = datum;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Edit 1: So as @bergi said, I can't return / throw from event-emitters, I need to promisify them. Here's how!

Comment: `return`ing and `throw`ing from event emitter handlers won't do any good. You cannot make `getFromYT` an `async function`, it's necessary to promisify with `new Promise`.

Comment: Well, haven't had to deal with event-emitters before, so the mistake. Corrected it. Hope that this is alright, @Bergi.